# How to pass arguments via go generate

Tags: go, generate

Here is how my project is structure

```
├── cmd
│   ├── orders
│   │   ├── main.go
└── scripts
    └── codegenerator.go
```

the `codegenerator.go` file is the file where i have put my code to generate the code. Here is the logic for `codegenerator.go`

- rename `main.go` to `old_main.go`
- read from `old_main.go` line by line and write to a new file called `main.go`
- insert new lines/code blocks based on markers/placeholder in `main.go`
- remove `old_main.go` file

The `go:generate` directive is in `main.go` like this

```
//go:generate go run ../../scripts/codegenerator.go
```

I ran `go generate` from command line and wanted to pass in 3 arguments so that they can be utilized in `codegenerator.go`. here is my command and the errors i got (i executed this command on path `cmd/orders`)

```
 $ go generate arg_one arg_two arg_three
can't load package: package arg_one: unknown import path "arg_one": cannot find module providing package arg_one
can't load package: package arg_two: unknown import path "arg_two": cannot find module providing package arg_two
can't load package: package arg_three: unknown import path "arg_three": cannot find module providing package arg_three
```

So the questions are

1. Am i running `go generate` properly?
2. How can i pass in arguments from `go generate` command line to the target script

Comment: The arguments are specified in the `//go:generate` comment.  If you need to specify the arguments on the command line, then it might be more appropriate to run the command directly than to use `go generate`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón so if the arguments changes for every code generation the go:generate isn't a good option?

Comment: The `go generate` command is not a good option in this scenario.  What problem are you trying to solve by using `go generate` vs. running the command directly?

Comment: Whenever we introduce a new table in our system we have to write some boiler plate code in our existing files. That code is mainly a copy paste except that based on table name new variables are created.

Comment: OK, but what is the reason for using `go generate` instead of running the command directly?  What is the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Was just going through `go generate` and thought I can use this to solve the problem. Currently I am using `make` file. I read through docs but couldn't find the solution so I posted here. I guess I have to stay with `make` file then.

Comment: If this only needs to run when you add a table, `go generate` seems like the wrong tool entirely; this should be a stand-alone executable. `go generate` is used for re-generatable code; e.g. anything where you'd pull down the repo and run an initial build sequence of `go get;go generate;go build` to reproduce the generated files then build the project.

Answer (score 5):

While I agree you may be better off using another solution, there isn't anything preventing usage of env vars (os specifics may vary)

```
➜  /tmp cat foo.go

package main

//go:generate python run.py $ARG

func main() {}
```

```
➜  /tmp cat run.py
import sys

print sys.argv[1]
```

```
➜  /tmp ARG=poop go generate foo.go
poop
```